How to install MEEP on Windows 11 using WSL?
I need to install MEEP on the work laptop, that means I cannot use Conda for license issues. So, I understand my next best choice is to install it through WSL. After trying to install it on WSL I get:
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt install meep
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package meep is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'meep' has no installation candidate

But I see at Ubuntu's website that package do exist.
And here I read it may be a GUI issue, but I understand this is no longer a problem for WSL on Windows 11. I have even tested this running DiffPDF's GUI with success.
Furthermore,
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS \n \l

End of the ubuntu.sources file:
Types: deb
URIs: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main universe restricted multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

## Ubuntu security updates. Aside from URIs and Suites,
## this should mirror your choices in the previous section.
Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main universe restricted multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Can't you download the package manually with something like curl within WSL or within Windows and copy it to the WSL directory and then install the package manually? This seems like a sources issue which can also be modified. None of the repoistorys you are looking at are listed here

Try sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y instead of just sudo apt update

You have Ubuntu 24.04.1 - you "found" there is meep in oracular, i.e. Ubuntu 24.10

@JaromandaX - I missed that factual element, good catch!

I had to update to latest Ubuntu version in order to have access to Meep.

You can find detailed instructions for Installing MEEP on Linux Subsystem here:
https://github.com/NanoComp/meep/discussions/2423

1 Install Ubuntu (with WSL version 2): use Microsoft store to download and install distro
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-a-data-science-environment-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-c4b390803dd
2 Install Conda (Miniconda):
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
bash miniconda.sh -b -p miniconda3
export PATH=miniconda3/bin:$PATH ---- path to miniconda3 bin folder
2.1 In case if the base (root) doesn't appear in the terminal:
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash (recommended)
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh (recommended)
or
export PATH=/home/<user /miniconda3/bin:$PATH
or
source /home/<user /miniconda3/bin/activate
This command will add the command in " " to bashrc file, so every time ubuntu starts, the code will be executed:
echo "source /home/<user /miniconda3/bin/activate" >> ~/.bashrc
Install meep from
-https://meep-hr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Installation/
or
-https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation/ (recommended)
The codes are copied here for convenience (3.1 and 3.2).

3.1 Meep:
conda create -n meep -c chogan -c conda-forge pymeep
source activate pmeep
or
conda create -n meep -c conda-forge pymeep pymeep-extras (recommended)
source activate meep
3.2 Parallel Meep:
conda create -n pmeep -c chogan -c conda-forge pymeep-parallel
source activate pmeep
or
conda create -n pmeep -c conda-forge pymeep==mpi_mpich_ (recommended)
source activate pmeep
use following codes if you want to install packages on meep environment:
conda install -c conda-forge <some-package>

4.1 install jupyterlab on meep environment
conda activate meep
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
4.1.1 Access to Jupyter
conda activate meep
jupyter lab --no-browser
jupyter notebook --no-browser
Copy the the URL to your browser in windows.
4.2 Install Spyder
conda activate meep
conda install -c conda-forge spyder
conda install -c conda-forge ipython_genutils
conda install -c conda-forge spyder-kernels
4.2.1 Run Spyder on Mobaxterm (recommended):
Install Mobaxterms from https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html
Run the following codes:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev
sudo apt-get install alsa
sudo apt install libegl1-mesa libegl1
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit
Spyder
visit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gByRjL1HWII&ab_channel=ValeriaItzelArteagaMu%C3%B1iz if the display didn't work for spyder
4.2.2 Run Spyder on X-server:
Install VcXsrv on windows from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/
Run the followng codes:
sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev
sudo apt-get install alsa
sudo apt install libegl1-mesa libegl1
open .bashrc file as text or try the following code:
nano ~/.bashrc
copy and paste the following codes to the end of .bahsrc file:
export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2 /dev/null):0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
save the text file: (press Ctrl-X, then press y and the enter key if you used "nano ~/.bashrc" code)
Lunch VcXsrv and set the display number to 0 and select multiple windows
Enable the connection from public and private networks to VcXsrv from Firewall Setting
spyder
excute the following codes (examples/straight-waveguide.ipynb) to test your meep installation:

import meep as mp
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
print(mp.version)
cell = mp.Vector3(16,8,0)
geometry = [mp.Block(mp.Vector3(mp.inf,1,mp.inf),
center=mp.Vector3(),
material=mp.Medium(epsilon=12))]
sources = [mp.Source(mp.ContinuousSource(frequency=0.15),
component=mp.Ez,
center=mp.Vector3(-7,0))]
pml_layers = [mp.PML(1.0)]
resolution = 10
sim = mp.Simulation(cell_size=cell,
boundary_layers=pml_layers,
geometry=geometry,
sources=sources,
resolution=resolution)
sim.run(until=200)
eps_data = sim.get_array(center=mp.Vector3(), size=cell, component=mp.Dielectric)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(eps_data.transpose(), interpolation='spline36', cmap='binary')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
ez_data = sim.get_array(center=mp.Vector3(), size=cell, component=mp.Ez)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(eps_data.transpose(), interpolation='spline36', cmap='binary')
plt.imshow(ez_data.transpose(), interpolation='spline36', cmap='RdBu', alpha=0.9)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

In case of an error while importing meep (python -c 'import meep' or python3 -c 'import meep'):
conda activate meep
conda install -c conda-forge libgcc3
conda install -c conda-forge gsl

In the Jupyter lab or Spyder you should be able to see a waveguide and Ez-field distribution. Amazing!!!!
Tested on subsystem Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on windows 10.
visit following websites for more information on Meep installation:

https://novelresearch.weebly.com/installing-meep-in-windows-8-via-cygwin.html
http://jdj.mit.edu/wiki/index.php?title=Meep_Installation&printable=yes
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxIJTGiBdWs
http://lordamit.blogspot.com/2011/10/tutorial-meep-in-ubuntu-complete.html?view=classic
https://www.fzu.cz/~dominecf/meep/

